# Non piecewise $C^1$ solutions of conservation laws

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, hyperbolic-equations

I studied the following theorem:(Rankine-Hugoniot condition)

Let $u:\mathbb{R} \times [0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a piecewise $C^1$ function. Then $u$ is a weak solution if and only if the two of the following conditions are satisfied:

i) $u$ is a classical solution of in the domain where $u$ is $C^1$

ii) $u$ satisfies the jump condition

$$(u_+ -u_-) \eta_t +\sum\limits_{j=1}^d{f_j(u_+) -f_j(u_-)} \eta_x=0$$
My doubts...

i)Can we find an example of the  conservation law where solutions are not piecewise $C^1$(i.e the solution does not have a piece wise $C^1$ representative) so that we cannot apply Rankine-Hugoniot condition across the jump?

ii) Is there any weaker versions of this theorem so that piecewise $C^1$ can be relaxed?

Comment: For $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, $g(x-at)$ is a weak solution of $u_t+au_x=0$, $u(x,0)=g(x)$ (you have to know that, as you asked [weak solution of transport(advection) equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2864724/weak-solution-of-transportadvection-equation)). $u_t+au_x=0$ can be written as $u_t+(f(u))_x=0$ with $f(u)=au$. Now it suffices to take your favorite "wild" $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.