# weak solution of linear transport (advection) equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations, transport-equation

How to show that $g(x-at)$ is the weak solution of the initial value problem
$$u_t+au_x=0$$
$$u(x,0)=g(x)$$ where $ g(x)\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$

**Definition:** $u$ is said to be the weak solution of the above initial value problem if
$$\int\limits_0 ^ {\infty} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} ({u{\phi}_t+au{\phi}_x})dxdt =\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\phi(x,0)dx$$  $\forall \phi \in C_c ^1(\mathbb{R} \times[0,\infty))$

Comment: You simply need to show that $u(x,t) = g(x-at)$ satisfies the integral equation for all $\phi\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}\times [0,\infty))$. Divergence theorem and integration by parts would be useful for you.

Comment: Can we apply integration by parts and divergence theorem as g is only $L^{\infty}$? Could u please give the complete proof.. I am unable to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change of variable can also be justified as follows:

Let $\Omega$ be an open set, $\Psi: \Omega \rightarrow \Psi(\Omega)$ be a $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism and $f:\Psi(\Omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measureble function. Then the change of variable formula is given by
\begin{eqnarray}\label{CVF}
\int\limits_{\Psi(\Omega)}f(x)dx=\int\limits_{\Omega}f(\Psi(x)) |J_{\Psi}(x)|dx             \quad \quad \quad (1)
\end{eqnarray}

Now, we apply the above formula with $\Omega=\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+$  and  $\Psi(x,t)=(x+at,t)$ so that $|J_{\Psi}(x)|=1,$ as below.

Consider
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+}u(x,t)(D_2\phi(x,t)+aD_1\phi(x,t))dxdt\\
&&=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+}g(x-at)(D_2\phi(x,t)+aD_1\phi(x,t))dxdt\\
&&= \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+}g(x)(D_2\phi(x+at,t)+aD_2\phi(x+at,t))dxdt \quad \because (1) \\
&&= \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+}g(x)(\partial_t \tilde{\phi}(x,t))dxdt  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad \quad\quad \quad \because \tilde{\phi}(x,t):=\phi(x+at,t) \\
&&= -\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)\tilde{\phi}(x,0)dx = -\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}u(x,0)\phi(x,0)dx.   \quad\quad \because \text{Fundamental theorem of Calculus}
\end{eqnarray}
This implies that $u(x,t)=g(x-at)$ satisfies the weak formulation.

Answer (score 2):

Let us make the change of variable $(\xi, \tau) = (x-at,t)$, in other words $(x,t) = (\xi + a\tau,\tau)$, so that
\begin{aligned}
&\phi_t = \phi_\xi \xi_t + \phi_\tau \tau_t = \phi_\tau - a\phi_\xi \\
&\phi_x = \phi_\xi \xi_x + \phi_\tau \tau_x = \phi_\xi \, .
\end{aligned}
Thus, using Fubini's theorem and integration by parts,
\begin{aligned}
\iint_{\Bbb R\times\Bbb R_+} u\, (\phi_t + a \phi_x)\, \text d x\,\text d t
&= \iint_{\Bbb R\times\Bbb R_+} u \phi_\tau\, \text d \xi\,\text d \tau \\
&= \iint_{\Bbb R_+\times\Bbb R} u \phi_\tau\, \text d \tau\,\text d \xi \\
&= \int_{\Bbb R}\left[u\phi\right]_{\tau\in\Bbb R_+}\text d\xi - \iint_{\Bbb R_+\times\Bbb R} \underbrace{u_\tau}_{u_t + au_x =0} \phi\, \text d \tau\,\text d \xi \\
&= -\int_{\Bbb R}\left.(u\phi)\right|_{t = 0}\text dx \, .
\end{aligned}
We have shown that the definition holds for all smooth $\phi$ with compact support. Hence, $u(x,t) = g(x-at)$ is a weak solution to the Cauchy problem of the advection equation. Note that there is a sign mistake in OP.

---

Note that $u$ does not need to be continuous to apply integration by parts as above (see [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), §*Extension to other cases*, and [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_solution), §*A concrete example*).

Comment: please explain me the change of variable. I think it is slightly different from the standard change of variable as derivative is involved in the integrand. It will be nice if you could suggest me the reference for the proof of this change of variable

Comment: @Rosy I have added more details to my answer.