# Is the weak solution of the transport equation $\left(\frac\partial{\partial t}+b\cdot\nabla_x\right)u=0$, $u(0)=u_0$, still be given by $u_0(x-tb)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, transport-equation

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $b\in\mathbb R^d$ and $u_0:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable.

We can easily show that the unique (classical) solution of \begin{align}\left(\frac\partial{\partial t}+b\cdot\nabla_x\right)u&=0&\text{in }(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R^d;\tag1\\ u&=u_0&\text{on }\{0\}\times\mathbb R^d\tag2\end{align} is given by $$u(t,x):=u_0(x-tb)\;\;\;\text{for }(t,x)\in[0,\infty)\times\mathbb R^d.\tag3$$

> If $u_0$ is not differentiable, will a "weak" solution of $(1)$ and $(2)$ still be given by $(3)$? And is this weak solution still unique?

To be precise, let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open, $H:=L^2(\Omega)$, $V:=H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $u_0\in V'$. Say that $u\in\mathcal L^2((0,\infty),V)$ is a weak solution of $(1)$ and $(2)$, with $\mathbb R^d$ replaced by $\Omega$, if $$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\langle\varphi,u(t)\rangle_H=-\langle b\varphi,\nabla u(t)\rangle_{L^2(\Omega,\:\mathbb R^d)}\tag4$$ and $$\langle\varphi,u(0)\rangle=u_0\tag5$$ for all $\varphi\in V$.

Since this definition requires $u$ to take values in $V$ (and not only in $V'$), I guess we need to assume that $u_0\in V$ (but I would also like to know if there is also a sensible notion of solution which takes values in $V'$) such that we can at least ask whether such a weak solution could be given by $(3)$. However, there is still the problem that $u_0$ is only an equivalence class and hence we cannot make sense of the evaluation $u_0(x-tb)$ of $u_0$ at $x-tb$ ...

Comment: That the "essentially unique" weak solution of the transport equation is given by propagating the initial condition even when the initial condition is irregular is really standard, see e.g. Evans. Only the matter of it being dual space-valued is novel here...

Comment: @Ian I've looked into Evans, but I've only found a passage where he's claiming that the weak solution is still of this form, but I couldn't find a proof. Could you tell me which page you mean? Or do you know an other reference?

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2875858) discussing the scalar case is related enough

Comment: @EditPiAf Thank you for the reference. However, it is quite clear to me that everything works using partial integration, but as I said before, isn't there a problem with the evaluation of an equivalence class?